# Web Application Loading Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

I have a web app that has several tree views. When the page loads i see the unordered lists and after a small latency the styling of the tree is rendered into the DOM.

Is there a way to mask the webapp, and have a spinner in the middle of the screen, and when everything on the page is fully rendered the spinner goes away and the mask fades out? Kind of like a semi transparent mask that you would see on a lightbox pop-up dialog.

Comment: You can use CSS to make a div you face out with JavaScript onLoad. If you need a spinner icon, see http://ajaxload.info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's semi-transparent you'll see the problem still. Add

```
<div id="loadingmask"></div>
```

before `</body>`. You might need to adjust its z-index if you have other z-indexes set.

CSS :

```
#loadingmask
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:#000 url(yourspinner.gif) center no-repeat;

}
```

jQ // when everything else has been done

```
$('#loadingmask').fadeOut(500, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

​

Comment: does it waits for background images from css? or it just simply loads html, css, js content?.

Comment: No, it doesn't wait. If the page is ready before the spinner loads why would you make the user wait for the spinner to load?

Comment: i mean not background of #loadingmask elemenent. i mean all background images in css file, that must be loaded for full page view. in my case, i have app that uses a lot of graphic elements as backgrounds in css. so if i create loading screen, it must load all images, that are used in css file.